# Is the milk of donkey halal?

Tags: halal-haram, animals

Is milk of donkey halal in Islam? Can anybody list the animals with halal milk? May Allah bless you all.

Answer (score 1):

The meat and milk of a wild donkey [onager] is halaal.  This is collected both by al-Bukhari and Muslim, a hadith narrated by Abu Qatadah:

> That once he was with Allah's Messenger. When he had covered some of
>   the way to Mecca, he and some companions of his, who were in the state
>   of lhram. remained behind the Prophet while Abu Qatada himself was not
>   in the state of Ihram. Abu Qatada, seeing an onager rode his horse and
>   asked his companions to hand him a whip, but they refused. He then
>   asked them to hand him his spear, but they refused. Then he took it
>   himself and attacked the onager and killed it. Some of the Companions
>   of Allah's Messenger ate of it, but some others refused to eat. When
>   they met Allah's Apostle they asked him about that. He said, **"It was
>   meal given to you by Allah."

[[al-Bukhari]](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/72/16)

There's is dispute whether the meat of a **domestic donkey** is forbidden, since none of the reports actually verbally quote the Prophets words.  Instead, they are words of **some of the companions** claiming the Prophet forbade.  Ahmed bin Hanbal said 15 companions considered it as disliked, i.e. makruh, and not outright haraam.

And I think our Shia brethren believe it's makruh.

> Can anybody list the animals with halal milk?

Safest route is to stick with all animals that are allowed to be eaten.  You can find the list of legal animals easily through search engine.  It'll be a long list.

Comment: I looked back into this subject, Concerning domestic donkey I didn't find any dispute because in Al-Bukhari and Moslem from Hadith Jabir Ibn Abdlah the prophet forbid eating its meat and from that the four madhaheb want to forbid its milk because it is coming from haram source. Sahib Al Ikna which is a Hanbaly imam considered it as Unclean "najas"

Answer (score 0):

Saoudian chikh say that drinking it without necessity is haram because the prophet forbid in khaybar war eating donkey because it is dirty. From that they conclude that anything that came from it is Haram.
As for other milk the rule in islam is every meal is halal as long as God (or his prophet) did not forbid it. It is hard to find list of all halal milk so I suggest that every time you have doubt you ask an inchala someone help you

Comment: Yeah you are right. I will summarize as that any food obtained from haram source is haram.